# Array is iterable on local machine, but not on Leetcode?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, debugging

I'm solving this [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/) (letter combinations found in phone number), and the solution seems to work on my machine, in vscode. Here is the code I am running, under the sample input of '23':

```js
/**
 * @param {string} digits
 * @return {string[]}
 */
 var letterCombinations = function(digits) {

    mapping = [ //this used to be an object in form {2: ['a','b', 'c'] (and so on...)}, i changed it to this to see if it fixed anything but it didn't
        [], 
        [], 
        ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
        ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
        ['g', 'h', 'i'], 
        ['j', 'k', 'l'], 
        ['m', 'n', 'o'], 
        ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], 
        ['t', 'u', 'v'], 
        ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    ] 
     
    letter_combinations = [];

    for(let letter of mapping[digits[0]]){
        let prefix = letter;
        for(let suffix of mapping[digits.slice(1)]){
            letter_combinations.push([prefix + suffix]);
        }
    }
    return letter_combinations;
};

console.log(letterCombinations('23'));
```

In VSCode/my machine, it seems to be working, as this is the output:

```js
[
  [ 'ad' ], [ 'ae' ],
  [ 'af' ], [ 'bd' ],
  [ 'be' ], [ 'bf' ],
  [ 'cd' ], [ 'ce' ],
  [ 'cf' ]
]
```

However, in Leetcode, I get this error:

```js
Line 24 in solution.js
    for(let letter of mapping[digits[0]]){
                             ^
TypeError: mapping[digits[0]] is not iterable
    Line 24: Char 30 in solution.js (letterCombinations)
    Line 41: Char 19 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 32: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 1251: Char 30 in loader.js (Module._compile)
    Line 1272: Char 10 in loader.js (Object.Module._extensions..js)
    Line 1100: Char 32 in loader.js (Module.load)
    Line 962: Char 14 in loader.js (Function.Module._load)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    Line 17: Char 47 in run_main_module.js
```

which seems to be telling me that 'mapping[digits[0]' is not iterable. Printing 'mapping[digits[0]' out to console on both Leetcode and in VSCode returns an array of ['a', 'b', 'c'], which should be iterable, right?

I think a way to work around this is to use a for...in loop, or a for(var;cond;step) loop and instead of 'letter', have it be 'mapping[digits[0]][index]', however I believe that this would be an inefficient workaround?

So I am wondering how I can directly iterate through mapping[digits[0]], or if not possible, why can't I?

I appreciate all the help, and forgive me if I'm missing something totally obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that you wrote only works when `digits.length === 2`

> Printing 'mapping[digits[0]' out to console on both Leetcode and in
> VSCode returns an array of ['a', 'b', 'c'], which should be iterable,
> right?

what if digits is an empty string `''`? `digits[0]` will return undefined

> I think a way to work around this is to use a for...in loop, or a
> for(var;cond;step) loop and instead of 'letter', have it be
> 'mapping[digits[0]][index]', however I believe that this would be an
> inefficient workaround?

switching to a normal `for` loop or using `forEach` won't change the number of iterations so they are not inefficient when compared to a `for...of` loop

also, `mapping[digits.slice(1)]` won't work when digits have a length of 3 because your mapping array only has elements with a max index of `9` (`'123'.slice(1)` returns 23 but `mapping[23]` is undefined)